# android ArrayList is empty after getter method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a class that implements getter and setter methods and related code as follows.

```
ArrayList<String> viewArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getView() {
return viewArray;
}
```

from my activity, I am trying to get acces to stored array like:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

al = parsedExampleDataSet.getView();
```

But "al" receives no data. However, when getView() is executed, viewArray is filled properly. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you giving `al` an initial value, only to replace that value with the result of calling `getView()`? It's not clear at what point anything is empty...

Comment: if parsedExampleDataSet.getView() returns a list, there should not be a problem. debug it, put a breakpoint on this line al = parsedExampleDataSet.getView(); and you will see getView() returns empty list. the code before it makes the list empty or something else.

Comment: there is no code before because when debugging, when getView() is executed, viewArray is filled properly. However al is not filled like viewArray. If more code will be helpful I will be glad to post it

Comment: Maybe you hide viewArray by other instance. Check hashCode of both object during debugging (in eclipse instance ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have make some good comments but I thought I'd take you through the code as I see it.

```
public class SomeClass {
    // this is local to this class only
    ArrayList<String> viewArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void process() {
       // i'm guessing there is some sort of processing method that is called
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getView() {
       return viewArray;
    }
}
```

Here's your activity class annotated with some details about the value of `a1`:

```
public class YourActivity {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void someMethod() {
        // here a1 will be the same blank List you initialized it with
        // unless someMethod() has been called before or a1 modified elsewhere
        al = parsedExampleDataSet.getView();
        // after the call to getView, a1 is now a reference to SomeClass.viewArray
        // the ArrayList that a1 was initialized with is then garbage collected
    }
}
```

Please edit your question to explain more what you are having problems with.